# List Adapter gets new or updated list before calling re-submit after observing LiveData

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using ListAdapter to show list of music files by observing livedata , after observing updaedMusicList will be submitted. but when I change musicFile from list and try to resubmit , before resubmit  the list adapter gets the automatically new values , and that leads to not update in UI unless I scroll or refresh/restart UI.

I tried to solve by debugging the code and I reach conclusion that List Adapter gets the new values before resubmitting the updated List

Comment: Please add your code so we better help with your issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.